# How to get specific characters in between 2 characters?

Tags: python

Let's say I have two Strings

```
String1= "[|123|456|789|]" 
             1   2   3

String2= "[|1234|5678|9|]" 
             1   2   3
```

But every time I get this String, I want to extract the numbers on spot number 2 in between the two pipe symbols.

Right now I am doing `String_I_Need = String1[6:9]`

That works, for Strings where there are three numbers on spot 2. If there are four numbers it will skip out one.

How can I get all four of them? And then some other time just all three or just maybe two?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Use the `split()` method to break up the string at pipe symbols.

```
String_I_Need = String1.split('|')[2]
```

Answer (score 1):

If your string always looks the same and you always want the numbers between the two `|` characters, you can do the following:

```py
string1 = "[|1234|5678|9|]"
result = string1.split('|')[2]
```

Answer (score 0):

the python programming language counts from 0 (like most modern languages) and will always miss out the first and last if you do something like `string1[6:9]`

instead, you can try using lists like `List1 = [123, 456, 789]`

then you can just use the different list indices, so if I want the value of the first element, I can type can type
`List1[1]`

```
>>> List1 = [1, 123, 456]
>>> print(List1[0])
1
```

Comment: this does not answer the OP's question

Comment: it improves the way he did it 

Comment: @AklonSight it changes the problem to a different one

Comment: true, but makes it much easier to handle✅